# Conda upgrade python version and remove older version

Tags: python, conda

**Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**

Conda is my python pkg manager. I have both python 3.8.3 and python 3.6.9 installed in conda. I want to remove both of them and install a newer version, say python3.8.5. How do I do that?

I have searched the internet but all I got was new installation than removal of old.

Answer (score 0):

I uses conda prompt to handle python version.

1. turn your conda prompt and activate your environment(ex) 'activate (YOUR ENVIRONMENT NAME)'
2. put 'conda search python' and you'll get versions you can download
3. if you checked 3.8.5 there, type 'install conda python=3.8.5'

hope this would help you.

Comment: does that remove the older python versions? I guess no.

Comment: I have the same question as Sayan Dey and also could not find out to uninstall old Python versions.